# At my wits end on sleep()

Tags: php

I've got sleep(n) in a loop that is intended to do output on a periodic cycle.

But when I run the loop, nothing happens until all of the seconds in the intended loop duration accrue collectively, after which all of the output comes spilling out at once.

Help.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: Are you using output buffering?

Comment: I read this question and thought - me too, I'm an insomniac. On a serious note, some code might help so we can see what's going on.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't be using PHP for dynamic output?

Comment: While you might get lucky and have it work(or at least, seem to work when you test it), you should know that you aren't in a position to guarantee when a chunk of data gets sent to the users browser. There's many layers of software involved here, and between them and the network, many possibile points of buffering. In addition to some of the suggestions made so far, you might need to play with the webserver too. But that's about as far as you can go. It simply wont work for some of your users.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks, thanks for replying.

I have to use PHP, because it's the only broad spectrum language available on the host.  Please see my followup question below (near bottom today).

Comment: (I plan to output text into my web space on the host site.  No output for this into client; I'm just testing sleep states and program consistency with the equivalent of printf debugging.)

Comment: chris, you actually got me thinking that what I really need isn't addressed by the stuff I'm outputing to the browser at all.  (Now that I've had some sleep.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

try that:

```
ob_end_flush (); // just in case
while (1) {
  echo 'wait for it<br/>'.PHP_EOL;
  flush ();
  sleep (2);
}
```

Comment: mathroc, thank you for this.  But my shared host throws a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ob_flush_end()"

What does this mean?

Comment: Please see my new comment below.

Comment: I have really no clue of what is wrong with your code, maybe you can try to `echo 'Almost there<br/>';` instead of writing it outside php..

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to flush() the output buffer after each piece of output?

Comment: Agreed, every time you echo/print output, call 'flush()' immediately after.

Comment: Thank you both.  I have another question toward that end (please see below):

Answer (score 1):

Argh, the site's not letting me add comment to mathroc's latest.  So I'll put it here:

It didn't work for me. But the following is really weird: I accidentally stumbled upon some other sleep code on the web that I stuck in front of what I've got:

```
<HTML> 
<BODY> 

$c=0; 
while($c <$chunks){ 
$rand = rand(2000000, 6000000); 
echo '<br> . . . sleeping for ' . round(($rand / 1000000),2) . ' seconds . . . zzzzzzzzzzzzzz<br>'; 
flush(); 
usleep($rand); 
$c++; 
} 

WHAT I'VE GOT BEGINS HERE: 
<br /> 
<br /> 
This page is loading.<br /> 
<?php  
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){ 
 flush(); sleep(2); 
?> 
 Almost there...<br /> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
<?php flush(); sleep(2); ?> 
Done.<br /> 

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

...and now the lower block of code sleeps fine, sequentially. Output is properly staggered (instead of arriving all in a lump at the end of 10 secs).

It's weird because I don't know what the above is doing that would make everything in the block below work all right. If I remove it, my block doesn't work (i.e., the output accumulates and then spills en masse at the end). If I remove only bits and pieces of the code above, then my thing wants to jump forward a little (but sequentially outputs the rest fine).

I have no idea what the preceding code is doing that makes my (latter block) work the way it should, or how to abbreviate it so that it still makes the latter block fully work, or even how to make the above code invisible on the page while still allowing the latter block to work accurately.

(I've tested the script on both Windows 7 Caucho Resin PHP 5 and Linux Apache CGI-BIN PHP 4 platforms. Identical results.)

Comment: Web servers are designed and optimized to turn around requests as quickly as possible. By all means, have a long sleep in a CLI program which runs properly as a daemon - but not like this in a web page!

Comment: this really looks like some experimental/discovering stuffs. might be way easier.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you should be using flush() instead of sleep().

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: ...or the two in conjunction?

Comment: After further review, it should be the two in conjunction. I thought the user wanted to flush output to the browser on each iteration without any delay.  The original question isn't completely clear.